# Reloading or Refreshing JSON and HTML div load order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am trying to create some code that will allow me to pull and display stock data for a Smart Mirror Project that I am building.

I have gotten it to display all the information but am not able to update the stock data. I want it to update the information every 5 seconds but when I do this, it basically goes on repeat and continues to output all the stocks over and over, off the page.

How can I get it to reload the data without reloading the entire page and how can I tell that it is working? Is it possible add a css element that flashes the prices yellow whenever the price changes?

Here is my code in fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/Aurum115/2kbpt91z/17/

Edit: To clarify the second part. I basically want to still store the old price and compare it to the new price temporarily and quickly flash the text yellow if it has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are appending the new HTML to the existing HTML.

To solve your problem, you need to delete the existing contents of the divs that your are updating. You should add the following code after the setInterval(,,, line:

```
$("#title").html("");
$("#livePrice").html("");
$("#stockTicker").html("");
$("#livePercent").html("");
$("#liveData").html("");
```

Unfortunately, it does result in a "flicker" each time you reload. To reduce this, in cases where you have a fixed number of rows, you can label each row 1-X (and use the same number for the cells in each row) and then simply overwrite the contents of each cell on each row as you update...

In my view, if you aren't worried about the order that the stocks appear, you should use a table and give id's to the cells that relate to each stocks price and change (e.g. for Apple the cell ids could be: price_NASDAQ:AAPL, change_NASDAQ:AAPL). You then simply use $("#price_NASDAQ:AAPL").html(...) to update the price and $("#change_NASDAQ:AAPL").html(...) to update the change.

If you want something to happen (like a flash) use $("#price").css("background-color", "...") to change the color and use setInterval(...) to wait for a short time before changing the color back...

Comment: Thank you for your help! I haven't created a table before. Would making a table require a variable for each element such as price?

Comment: Here is a link to a jsfiddle page with a sketch of a solution: https://fiddle.jshell.net/t6we5xmt/2/